# Joining of three tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables (photos, photos_details) joined by a LEFT JOIN and I want to JOIN a third one (favourites) to see if the photo is favourited or not.
This is the current SQL query:

```
SELECT photos_details.title, photos_details.description, photos.url
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN photos_details ON photos.photo_id = photos_details.photo_id
```

favourites table basically contains 2 columns (PRIMARY) id and photo_id

Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Other than just being obnoxious and adding a 'JOIN favourites on...' section right after your left join... what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to see if it has been favorited ever?  How many favorites?  I'm confused by your goal.

Comment: I want to know if the photo has been favorited or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` against the favorites table and determine with a `CASE` whether the `favorites.photo_id` is null, transforming it into a boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the photo has a favorite.

```
SELECT
   photos_details.title,
   photos_details.description, 
   photos.url,
   CASE WHEN favorites.photo_id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END as is_favorited
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN photos_details ON photos.photo_id = photos_details.photo_id
LEFT JOIN favorites ON photos.photo_id = favorites.photo_id
```

To get only favorited photos, add

```
WHERE favorites.photo_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: How can I add a WHERE clause against that favorited? I tried WHERE favorited=1 but it didn't work.
Saying that I want to list all favorited pictures.

Comment: @SlimB Try the addition above

Comment: Thanks that worked :) I used before != '' but I guess IS NOT NULL is much better.